# R: how to create a matrix with results of the following form without using a loop

Tags: r, dataframe, apply

Here is an example. I have 3 variables (actually are 10.000) and i create a new variable by just doing an average of some of this variables. For example, just variable x1 and x3 (in the example).

The output is to create a matrix with the results of using a loss measure between the variable and that new variable. As you can see in the example. I want to generalize this example for cases where the new variable is not just the average of 2 or 3 variables, it can be of 5.000 variables and then do the results calculate

any help i will appreciate.

```
 x<-data.frame(x1= runif(10,min = 0,max = 2000), x2=runif(10,min = 0,max = 1000), x3= runif(10,min = 0,max = 14000))

 y1<- rowMeans(x[,c("x1","x2")])

 y2<- rowMeans(x[,c("x1","x3")])

 y3<- rowMeans(x)

 results<-cbind(0.5*abs(x$x1-y1)+0.5*abs(x$x2-y1),
0.5*abs(x$x1-y2)+0.5*abs(x$x3-y2), 
0.33*abs(x$x1-y3)+0.33*abs(x$x3-y3)+0.34*abs(x$x2-y3))
```

UPDATE:

Actually what was meant is that one can leave more than one column out. Not just one. But also the case where all the columns are used.

Answer (score 1):

This might be more efficiently accomplished by:

```
cbind( 
rowMeans( abs( x[-3] - rowMeans(x[-3])  )  ),
rowMeans( abs( x[-2] - rowMeans(x[-2])  )  ),
rowMeans( abs( x - rowMeans(x)  )  )
     )
```

It wasn't exact because the last column was actually:

```
(1/3)*abs(x$x1-y3)+(1/3)*abs(x$x3-y3)+(1/3)*abs(x$x2-y3))
```

This function would return that metric on a leave-one-out (any number of columns basis:

```
L1.leaveout <- function(dfrm,cidx) rowMeans( abs(dfrm[-cidx]  - rowMeans(dfrm[-cidx])))
```

And it could be deployed in the form you requested in this manner for the particular example you offered:

```
do.call( cbind, c( lapply(2:length(x),     #leave out each singly except first
                   function(z) L1.leaveout(x, z) ),
               list(rowMeans( abs( x-rowMeans(x) ) ))  # last column
              )
   )
```

Comment: thanks for your reply is useful but not quite what i was asking. Because is not a leave one out problem. For example if there were four variables x1 x2, x3, x4 you will still want to create a new variable just using x1 and x2 and not x3 and x4. That is why i find it challenging. Maybe for many of you not. :) Thanks again for your help.

Comment: I think it was exactly what you were asking. The function was set up so that you could "leave out" more than one column at a time. The last example showed how it could be  used to just leave just one out at a time but it wasn't limited to that deployment. If you edit your question to actually describe a particular request, then I'm fairly sure that this can address that other situation.

Comment: You are right i have to make it more general the question. I just did. Thanks @42-